# X11 controlling root window or setting a window to be the background window (wallpaper)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, i3, wallpaper

I would like an animated background image. Or better, to make an application be the background, with no interactivity, so I don't accidentally click on it.

I've seen many discussions about setting images as background, but is there a way to set an arbitrary application as the background window?

I've found this Gifsice snippet on the Arch BBS:
`gifsicle --animate --new-window root someAnimatedGif.gif` but it just opened a regular window (I'm using i3 with LightDM on Arch).

I've tried executing it when i3 starts (same result as running it from xterm) and putting it in `.Xinitrc`, which produced nothing.

How/where should I run gifview and is it possible to use another application, such as VLC, as the background window and why does `gifview --new-window root` not change the root?

Comment: It may depend on Window-Manager, Desktop-system (Kde, gnome, fwm, etc). Kde, and some others, add a window above the root, but behind everything else.

Comment: so the root window can be placed in front of other windows if the WM puts it there?
this also doesn't really answer whether the root can be any window of any program

Comment: That is not what I Wrote. I said that some desktop-systems put a windows covering the root window. Therefore the root does not have to be the background. This is not the same as the root can be in front, the root is **always** behind all others.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? Tell us without the jargon. Are you trying to write to the background, copy the background to somewhere else, or something else.

Comment: I thought it can be in front because `gifview --new-window root` opened a normal window
I'm trying to figure out if the root window can be replaced by any other window or can act as anything else besides a static background.

Comment: From gifview manual “Display the next GIF input in a new **child** of an existing X window.”.  Therefore the new window is a child of root.

Comment: I based it on [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=73902)
not sure what others did differently or if there was a change in Gifsicle since then, but many reported that it works.
So it's not possible to replace the root window?

Comment: Based on your link I think you are trying to change the background image, possibly you are trying to have an animation as background. From also your question I think you are trying to make an application be the background, probably with no interactivity.

Comment: That is correct. Changing the background to a static image works, but not the rest.

Comment: There's _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP (https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html#idm139870830002400) but the WM has to support it

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
exec /usr/bin/gifview  --animate -w root /path/to/image.gif
```